# how to access static variable in cakephp 2

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am using the following code to check the logged in user's group (cakephp 1.3)

Session->read('Auth.User.user_group_id') != User::USERLEVEL_USER) :?> 
(this is in .ctp file)

and now am migrating to cakephp 2. and this code is not working. 
cant find any results when I googled .

Could anyone shed some light on this

Comment: showing Fatal error: Class 'User' not found

Answer (score 0):

in cakephp 2.x you're sending variables to view, so you don't have access to User class. you should get instance of this class in controller and send it as a variable to view.

please use this plugin to improve your debugging skills:
https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit

Answer (score 0):

in cakephp 2, you can not use static variables User::USERLEVEL_USER like this. What I do is, set a view parameter using $this->set(), and added needed constants one by one and use that parameter name inside view.ctp file.

```
$this->set('USERLEVEL_USER', User::USERLEVEL_USER);
```

in this way, you can use USERLEVEL_USER as a variable inside view.ctp file.